# setforegroundwindow setactivewindow what's the difference (pinvoke)?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Could anybody explain me what's the difference with setactivewindow with setforegroundwindow (using pinvoke from www.pinvoke.net/#

For first look, you can tell me that it set active window and the another get to the front the window, but.. hey! the first one also bring to the front of desktop, isn't it? So if i want keep window in front of all windows and make active (because i want operate on it, i don't see another way yet) which one should i use?

Hope i write logically, sorry for english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check their documentation on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646311%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I think in your case you need to use SetForegroundWindow